# Sending metadata to a monaco completionProvider

Tags: monaco-editor

Completion providers are typically registered at a global level like so:

```
    languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
      myNewLanguageName,
      new CompletionAdapter()
    )
```

Completion providers must define a method based on the following type def:

```
        provideCompletionItems(model: editor.ITextModel, position: Position, context: CompletionContext, token: CancellationToken): ProviderResult<CompletionList>;
```

Because the completion provider is registered globally, I'd like to find a way to pass metadata into the call to the provideCompletionItems function. My preference would be to send it as a bag of optional contextual data. This could be as a param to provideCompletionItems, or as metadata to tack onto the model (1st param).

I know this is "just Javascript" and I could, in theory, just stick data onto the editor model, but I'd prefer to learn if there is a canonical way to achieve what I'm asking, and at the very least not violate the type definitions carefully crafted for Monaco. In other words

```
const model = editor.getModel()
model.myBagOfStuff = {blah: 'some value'}
```

would work just fine, but it violates the type definitions and I'd prefer / hope to learn about an interface on the editor model that provides this intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what I did too. I defined an own editor model with additional data. That's for model specific data.

Additionally, you can have global symbol tables (holding e.g. function names or global symbols) and access them in your completion provider.